# Conda-build detects conflicts on relatively basic projects

Tags: python, pip, conda, pypi

I'm trying to make [this](https://pypi.org/project/read-ice/) PyPI package into a conda package.
These are the requirements as per the setup.py file. Not too demanding I think?

```
install_requires=['pandas',
                  'numpy',
                  'scipy',
                  'matplotlib',
                  'docutils',
                  'pyproj',
                  'Pygments',
                  'netCDF4',
                  'cartopy']
```

But then when I type `conda-build read_ice` into the terminal (with a virtual env activated), conda detects a whole load of conflics. This seems odd, as I installed all the packages with conda and the program runs fine on my machine. Here's the relevant part of the error message I think.

```
Package python-dateutil conflicts for:
cartopy -> matplotlib -> python-dateutil[version='>=1.5']
matplotlib -> python-dateutil
pandas -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.5.*|>=2.6.1|>=2.7.3']

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
cartopy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
pandas -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
netcdf4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
pyproj -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
python=3.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
numpy=1.11 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
matplotlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
scipy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]

Package mkl_fft conflicts for:
pyproj -> numpy -> mkl_fft[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']
pandas -> numpy[version='>=1.15.4,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_fft[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']
scipy -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_fft[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']
cartopy -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_fft[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']
netcdf4 -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_fft[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']
matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_fft[version='>=1.0.14,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4|>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']

Package libcurl conflicts for:
netcdf4 -> libnetcdf[version='>=4.7.3,<5.0a0'] -> libcurl[version='>=7.59.0,<8.0a0|>=7.61.0,<8.0a0|>=7.61.1,<8.0a0|>=7.63.0,<8.0a0|>=7.68.0,<8.0a0']
pyproj -> proj[version='>=7.0.1,<7.0.2.0a0'] -> libcurl[version='>=7.69.1,<8.0a0']
cartopy -> proj[version='>=7.0.1,<7.0.2.0a0'] -> libcurl[version='>=7.69.1,<8.0a0']

Package python conflicts for:
scipy -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
matplotlib -> pyparsing -> python[version='>=3']
cartopy -> owslib -> python[version='>=3.6']
python=3.8
pygments -> setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
pygments -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
pandas -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.7.3'] -> python
netcdf4 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
pandas -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
matplotlib -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
pip -> wheel -> python
docutils -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
pyproj -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
cartopy -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Package scipy conflicts for:
scipy
cartopy -> scipy

Package six conflicts for:
cartopy -> six
pandas -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.7.3'] -> six[version='>=1.5']
numpy=1.11 -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> six
matplotlib -> cycler[version='>=0.10'] -> six[version='>=1.5']
scipy -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> six

Package certifi conflicts for:
matplotlib -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
pygments -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
netcdf4 -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']

Package numpy conflicts for:
matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.3.1,<3.3.2.0a0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.15.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0']
cartopy -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0']
pyproj -> numpy
netcdf4 -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.0,<2.0a0']
numpy=1.11
matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0']
scipy -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0']
pandas -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.12.1,<2.0a0|>=1.13.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.15.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0|>=1.9']
cartopy -> matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.15.1,<2.0a0']

Package pyproj conflicts for:
cartopy -> owslib -> pyproj[version='>=2']
pyproj

Package wheel conflicts for:
pip -> wheel
python=3.8 -> pip -> wheel

Package setuptools conflicts for:
matplotlib -> setuptools
pygments -> setuptools
cartopy -> matplotlib -> setuptools
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools
pip -> setuptools
netcdf4 -> setuptools

Package matplotlib conflicts for:
matplotlib
cartopy -> matplotlib

Package jpeg conflicts for:
cartopy -> pillow -> jpeg[version='>=9b,<10a']
netcdf4 -> libnetcdf[version='>=4.7.3,<5.0a0'] -> jpeg[version='>=9b,<10a']

Package intel-openmp conflicts for:
scipy -> mkl[version='>=2019.4,<2021.0a0'] -> intel-openmp
numpy=1.11 -> mkl[version='>=2019.4,<2021.0a0'] -> intel-openmp
```

Ideally I want to suppress this 'error', as the code clearly runs fine on my machine.

Comment: How are you building it? `conda skeleton pypi read-ice` followed by `conda build read-ice`?

Comment: Yes, that's it.